# What is the shortcut in mac to remove text left to the curser till the start of the line in terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

For instance, I type "aaa bbb" in the terminal and I put my cursor between "aaa" and "bbb". I am pretty sure there is a shortcut to remove "aaa" in one operation anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows is `Ctrl + Delete`

On Mac it will be `Command + Delete`

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it does not work in my terminal. I used mac and tried command + delete but nothing happened